# Sudo does not work in chroot

Tags: linux, sudo, chroot

I would like to be able to use the sudo command in a chroot environment.

I start the chroot as follows:

```
chroot /debian-squeeze /bin/bash
```

Now I'm logged in as root in the chroot. I can do `su user` to log in as a user named `user`. Now, `sudo` does not work:

```
user@HD:/$ sudo ls
sudo: must be setuid root
```

Some diagnostics:

```
user@HD:/$ which sudo
/usr/bin/sudo

user@HD:/$ ls -al /usr/bin/sudo
-rwsr-xr-x 2 root root 143884 May 23  2012 /usr/bin/sudo

user@HD:/$ ls -aln /usr/bin/sudo
-rwsr-xr-x 2 0 0 143884 May 23  2012 /usr/bin/sudo

root@HD:/# cat /etc/sudoers
Defaults    env_reset
root    ALL=(ALL) ALL
user ALL=(ALL) ALL
%sudo ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

As root, I can execute `sudo` without error.

Can anyone explain me why `sudo` (or `setuid`) does not work like this?

Comment: [This page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BasicChroot) might explain what you are after.

Comment: @Simplexion I see nothing on that page that might answer this question.

Comment: Show output of mount

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is that `/debian-squeeze` is on a separate filesystem mounted without `defaults` or `suid`. The kernel will ignore the setuid bit on filesystems mounted without `suid` (`defaults` implies `suid`). To fix it:

```
mount -o remount,suid /debian-squeeze
```

Comment: If su works than this is not the case...

Comment: Thanks, this was indeed the solution.

(su worked because I was already root user when I executed su.)

Comment: Be carefull, someone can now go to `/debian-squeeze` without `chroot` and use `sudo`.